# R read csv with comma in column

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

**Update 2020-5-14**

Working with a different but similar dataset from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/airbnb/boston?select=listings.csv), I found `read_csv` seems to work fine. I haven't tried it with the original data yet though.

Although the replies didn't help solve the problem because my question was not correct, Shan's reply fits the original question I posted the most, so I accepted his answer.

**Update 2020-5-12**

I think my original question is not correct. Like mentioned in the comment, the data was quoted. Although changing the separator made the 11582 row in R look the same as the 11583 row in excel, it doesn't mean it's "right". Maybe there is some incorrect line switch due to inappropriate encoding or something, and thus causing some of the columns to be displaced. If I open the data with notepad++, the instance at row 11583 in excel is at the 11596 row.

---

**Original question**

I am trying to read the `listings.csv` from [this dataset in kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/brittabettendorf/berlin-airbnb-data#listings_summary.csv)  into R. I downloaded the file and wrote the code`read.csv('listing.csv')`. The first column, the column `id`, is supposed to be numeric. However, it shows:

```
listing$id[1:10]
 [1] 2015  2695  3176  3309  7071  9991  14325 16401 16644 17409
13129 Levels: Ole Berl穩n!,16736423,Nerea,Mitte,Parkviertel,52.55554132116211,13.340658248460871,Entire home/apt,36,6,3,2018-01-26,0.16,1,279\n17312576,Great 2 floor apartment near Friederich Str MITTE,116829651,Selin,Mitte,Alexanderplatz,52.52349354926847,13.391003496971203,Entire home/apt,170,3,31,2018-10-13,1.63,1,92\n17316675,80簡 m of charm in 3 rooms with office space,116862833,Jon,Neuk繹lln,Schillerpromenade,52.47499080234379,13.427509313575928...
```

I think it is because there are values with commas in the second column. For example, opening the file with MiCrosoft excel, I can see one of the value in the second column is `Ole,Ole...`:
[image]

How can I read a csv file into R correctly when some values contain commas?

Comment: In the file you have linked to, rows in column 2 that contain commas are surrounded by quotes, so there shouldn't be any issues here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have access to the data in Excel, you can 'Save As' in Excel with a seperator other than comma (,). First go in to Control Panel –> Region and Language -> Additional settings, you can change the "List Seperator". Most common one other than comma is pipe symbol (|). In R, when you read_csv, specify the seperator as '|'.

Comment: Thanks. Some of the columns contain `|`, so I ended up using `{` as the separator. This indeed helped!

Comment: Hello Sara. It is a common etiquette on StackExchange sites to "accept" the best of the answers provided to you. If any of the answers was acceptable to you, please accept so.

Comment: Yes I've accepted the answer that fits my original question the most with some added updates in case people get confused with my incorrect question.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this?

lsitings <- read.csv("listings.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

listings$name <- gsub(",","", listings$name) -  This will remove the comma in Col name

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the information in the second column, then you can always delete it (in Excel) before importing into R. The `read.csv` function, which calls `scan`, can also omit unwanted columns using the `colClasses` argument. However, the `fread` function from the **data.table** package does this much more simply with the `drop` argument:

```
library(data.table)
listings <- fread("listings.csv", drop=2)
```

If you *do* need the information in that column, then other methods are needed (see other solutions).